# Cordova - Capture photo / video with the same command

Tags: android, ios, cordova, android-camera, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic, NGCordova ( http://ngcordova.com/docs/#Capture ) and the Capture plugin, trying to start a new hybrid app. I figured out how to use it to capture a photo, a video, a sound... But I have requirements a bit more complicated in my project.

I would like to be able to switch from photo to video and back inside of the camera view. Here is an example of what I would want to do, from the Wedpics app :

[image]

As you can see, on the bottom, there is the possibility to change from pic to vid and back. Also, there is the possibility to choose a pic from the gallery - which is good but no mandatory.

Now, is this possible to do with Capture plugin ? If not, is there another plugin that gives better capabilities ? Or, if there is not, would someone be able to tell me if it's at least doable with a hybrid app ? If yes, I could simply try and make my own plugin for iOS and Android...

Thank you very much ahead !

[EDIT] Okay, there is absolutely no plugin that gives this, surprisingly. It surprises me enough for me to ask, really, if someone that already worked on that type of things could answer this : is it possible to make ? I mean, there could be a problem regarding the returned data, with no way to detect what was returned or something like this, and that would be why no one did it...

If someone can confirm me it's doable, I might give it a try, or look for a freelancer to do it for me !

Thanks again !

Comment: The capture plugin just starts your device's default capture app and get the result back. If you want to have custom behaviour you'll have to use other plugin that have it's own view. I've searched video capture plugins and have found very few. Of course, if you're willing to write your own plugin with native code, anything is doable.Or maybe you could have a look at the getUserMedia HTML5 API to build a pure html5 solution, but I don't think it would work for old versions of android.

Comment: Exactly, it starts the default, with picture or video lock, but not both. I would have loved to have access to both. I thought about the HTML5 solution but doesn't think it would feel like native. Will try it anyway... If nothing exists then well I will be forced to do my own plugin / pay someone to do it.

Comment: Okay, getUserMedia is not compatible with UIWebView

Comment: It's 2019 and there seems to still be no plugin that does this (though https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview is somewhat closer). @JeremyBelolo did you every find a workable solution?